# IIS 7.5 error on a DLLImport call

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

I have an error running a asmx WebService that uses asp.net 2.0 on IIS 7.5. The webservice calls a method from a dll using the Dllimport call. The point where the call is made is where the error happens. However I get no exceptions, just ERR_CONNECTIO_RESET from any explorer.

What i've tried:

- The dll is located in the right place, the bin folder. I tried moving
  it to system32 and other locations. However if I change the name of
  the dll on the DLLIMPORT call i do get an error of not locating the
  dll, which means it does finds the dll, just crashes on the method.
- I also used GetLastWin32Error() and got the message 127
  ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND. Not sure if it's relevant, however is something
  I tried too.
- If I run the Webservice on debug from VisualStudio, I get no error on
  the call. So the error is when running on IIS.
- I also tried on a older machine with IIS 6 on Windows XP and I get no
  error. This make me think it has to do with a security issue, because
  when I created the website on IIS I got this screen:

[IIS 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IARzF.png)

And i haven't configurated any security options on IIS 7.5. So i tried this

http://forums.iis.net/post/2119656.aspx

Which are steps to configure the user with enough permissions over the folder. However, still no luck.

What i believe now could be, is something asociated to GOP (Group Policy Object). The pc I'm running this service is on a company network. I have admin rights and no firewall restrictions, however I don't know if IIS 7.5 uses something from a different user or needs different permissions.

All the other threads i've found don't have the right answer for me. Any help i could get is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a week of dealing with this, I found the problem. After finding out there are some Logs I could check on C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR i found the error code Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue.

After some long investigation, I found out that the message means the program is droping because of memorry corruption (As seen on this post [Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404569/connection-abandoned-by-reqqueue-problems) ). The dll I'm using is quite old and the people who generated didn't make a version who handles memory the correct way (At least for IIS 7.5), so I'm stuck with finding another library to do that work, or using a server with IIS 6.